# Defining Custom Services and Characteristics on tvOS

Tags: swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, tvos, ios9.1

I want to setup my new Apple TV running with tvOS as **a Bluetooth peripheral device with a custom service** so it can communicate with the counterpart iPad app (the iPad is the central Bluetooth device and can be thought of as a remote for the Apple TV app).

There's a programming guide from Apple in order to do this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks.html) but it seems to be hopelessly **outdated** (even the pre-release version of it):

According to the Release Notes of iOS 9.1 / tvOS the **init methods** of both the `CBMutableCharacteristic` class and the `CBMutableService` class **were removed** and are no longer available on tvOS (using XCode 7.1). You can find the related changes in the CoreBluetooth framework [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/releasenotes/General/tvOS90APIDiffs/Objective-C/CoreBluetooth.html).

I tried to directly use the `startAdvertising` method of the `CBPeripheralManager` class and it is calling the `peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising` delegate method without an error like this:

```
let peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager()
let myCustomServiceUUID = CBUUID(string: "12345678-ABCD-1234-ABCD-123456789ABC")

func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    if peripheral.state == .PoweredOn {
        print("Bluetooth state is OK.")
        self.startProvidingSecondScreenForTestsService()
        self.peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [self.myCustomServiceUUID]])
    }
}
```

But **I don't know how to exchange data this way** without any characteristic defined along the way.

**Did I miss something** here (maybe there's an alternative/better way of defining those objects) or **did Apple knowingly remove the functionality for custom services and characteristics** on the new Apple TV for some reason?

Comment: I agree; it seems that at this point it is not possible for a TVOS app to operate as a bluetooth peripheral.